# ValueError: Cannot assign : must be an instance

Tags: django, django-forms

So I am very new to Django, and I am trying to save a new instance of a model Ovelse, which has a foreign key that points to another model Okt. I have a view that contains a list over all the Okt instances, which links to all the Ovelse instances connected to each Okt.

Models.py

```
class Okt(models.Model):

def __str__(self):
    return '{}, uke {}, dag {}'.format(self.sykel_navn, self.sykel_uke, self.sykel_dag)


sykel_navn = models.CharField(max_length=8, default="Sykel 1")
sykel_dag = models.CharField(max_length=(1), choices=(SYKEL_DAGER))
sykel_uke = models.CharField(max_length=(1), choices=(SYKEL_UKER))
dato = models.DateTimeField('Dato på treningsøkt: ')
notater = models.CharField(max_length=400)


class Ovelse(models.Model):

okt = models.ForeignKey(Okt, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
ovelse_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=MUSKELGRUPPE_CHOICES)
ovelse_navn = models.CharField(max_length=20)
vekt = models.IntegerField(default=0, name='kg')
sets = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=2)
reps = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=2)

def __str__(self):
    return self.ovelse_navn
```

views.py

```
class OvelseCreateView(generic.CreateView):
model = Ovelse
template_name = 'trening/add.html'
form_class = OvelseForm

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.okt = self.kwargs.get('pk')
    return super(OvelseCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

forms.py

```
class OvelseForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Ovelse
    exclude = ['okt',]
    fields = ['ovelse_navn', 'ovelse_type', 'kg', 'sets', 'reps']

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(OvelseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['ovelse_type'].label = "Muskler brukt"
    self.fields['ovelse_navn'].label = "Navn på øvelsen"
    self.fields['kg'].label = "Antall kilo"
    self.fields['sets'].label = "Antall set"
    self.fields['reps'].label = "Antall reps"
```

When I try to submit the form, I get the error message: Cannot assign "1": "Ovelse.okt" must be a "Okt" instance, while i wish to create a new model of the instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are "injecting" a primary key itself, and not an `Okt` object, you should use `.okt_id` over `.okt`:

```
class OvelseCreateView(generic.CreateView):

    model = Ovelse
    template_name = 'trening/add.html'
    form_class = OvelseForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.okt_id = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        return super(OvelseCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Note that you can set your labels in the `Meta` class of the form, there is no need to override the `__init__` file for this:

```
class OvelseForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Ovelse
        exclude = ['okt',]
        fields = ['ovelse_navn', 'ovelse_type', 'kg', 'sets', 'reps']
        labels = {
            'ovelse_type': 'Muskler brukt',
            'ovelse_navn': 'Navn på øvelsen',
            'kg': 'Antall kilo',
            'sets': 'Antall set',
            'reps': 'Antall reps'
        }
```